# Enterprise Architect snap to grid doesn't work

Tags: diagram, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to use the "snap to grid" feature on Enterprise Architect Diagram mode and it seems like it's not working. All elements and connectors didn't snap to the defined grid size (they still moving freely - pixel by pixel - when I drag and move them).

Does somebody know how to snap all elements and connectors to grid or, at least, to move the connectors pixel by pixel - like elements do when pressing SHIFT + arrows?

Answer (score 4):

for that you should use 'Snap to Grid' option from 'Diagram' menu.
There you can select one of two options: 'Standard Grid' and 'Smart Placement'
Documentation says:

> - **Standard Grid** - constrains elements to the grid when they are added to diagrams
> - **Smart Placement** - places elements even distances away from other elements and spaces elements evenly
>
> *If neither of these options are enabled, the elements can be placed freely on the diagram.*

1. Ensure that you have that option enabled
2. If it is not working try to reload diagram after point 1

BTW. For alignment elements on a diagram you can use more options from context menu (select elements and click right button):
[image]